# Problems with Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I'm having problem with mapping two classes with composite keys.

The first class is Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Product {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductKey prodPK;
    @Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description", length = 80)
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "totalStock", columnDefinition = "double(8,2) default 0")
    private double totalStock;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "companyId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;
}
```

With this @EmbeddedId:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class ProductKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "sku", length = 50)
    private String sku;
    @Embedded
    private LotKey lot;
}
```

At the same time, this embedded class has as part of its composite key another composite key "LotKey"

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class LotKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "lot")
    private String lot;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company company;
}
```

which belongs to the class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Lots")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Lote {
    @EmbeddedId
    private LotKey lotpk;
    @Column(name = "stock")
    private double stock;
    @Column(name = "expirationDate", columnDefinition = "default current_timestamp()")
    private Date expirationDate;
}
```

But I'm having trouble referencing to them:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quantityProduct")
public class QuantityProduct{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "sku",
                    referencedColumnName = "sku"),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "lot")
    })
    private Product product;
    @Column(name = "quantity", columnDefinition = "double(8,2) default 0")
    private double quantity;
}
```

I am getting the following error

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh7gd.png)

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

In `QuantityProduct`, set also `referencedColumnName` in

```
 @JoinColumn(
                name = "lot")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried, but if I do it throws me the following exception

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(sku, lote) of uy.com.storagemodule.logic.ProductoCantidad.producto referencing uy.com.storagemodule.logic.Producto not mapped to a single property
 at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:333)
.
.
.

Comment: `lote`? Isn't it `lot` in `ProductKey`?